# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable in list

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I was trying out a program for legendre's function as given below, but it showed some error. I'm not used to arrays in Python, but know them in C++.

```
from math import *

j = 0
arr = [0 for i  in range (6)]
k= 3.75
arr[0]= 1
arr[1] = 1 
x0= -1
xf = 1
x= x0
h= 0.1

f1 = open('leg.dat', 'w')

while x< xf:
    for j in range(0,5):
        arr[j+2]= (arr[j] *(j*j + j -k)/((j+2)*(j+1)))
        print >>f1, x,(x**j)*(((j+2)(j+1)*arr[j]) - (j*(j-1)*arr[j]) - (2*j*arr[j]) + k*arr[j])
        x = x+h

f1.close ()
```

error shown :

```
print>>f1, x,(x**j)*(((j+2)(j+1)*arr[j]) - (j*(j-1)*arr[j]) - (2*j*arr[j]) + k*arr[j])

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
(j+2)(j+1)
```

Python is trying to call the `j+2` with `j+1` as argument.

```
>>> j = 1
>>> (j+2)(j+1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Did you mean `(j+2)*(j+1)`?

Comment: oops! got it!
 the program i'm trying to write is of legendre's function upto 4 terms and draw its graph. but even when i corrected that, the data points are giving 0 for every value of x. can u pls suggest a correction?

Comment: After removing writing to a file (and printing to stdout instead) your code produces the following output on my machine:
-1 5.75
-0.9 -6.975
-0.8 -11.7
-0.7 1.17548958333
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "55pkt.py", line 16, in <module>
    arr[j+2]= (arr[j] *(j*j + j -k)/((j+2)*(j+1)))
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Are you experiencing the same results?

Answer (score 1):

```
print >>f1, x,(x**j)*(((j+2)(j+1)*arr[j]) - (j*(j-1)*arr[j]) - (2*j*arr[j]) + k*arr[j])
                        ^^^  ^^^
```

You didn't specify an operation between these two values. Did you mean to multiply them?

```
print >>f1, x,(x**j)*(((j+2)*(j+1)*arr[j]) - (j*(j-1)*arr[j]) - (2*j*arr[j]) + k*arr[j])
```